# Update form data in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form created by django. I do the insert without any difficalty, but when I want to use it in edit mode, when I click the form submit button, and I debug the code, request.POST is sent empty; that's because I send the parameter "id" to the view. (As when I remote this parameter, I have the values in request.POST). but what should I do?

models.py:

```
class Urls(models.Model):

    url = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
    )
```

forms.py:

```
class SaveUrl(forms.Form):
    url = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Url',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':32})
    )
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('systemSettings.views',
    url(r'^$',
        'systemSettings',
        name='systemSettings'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$',
        'editSystemSetting',
        name='editSystemSetting'),
)
```

in template,urlsSetting.html:

```
<form action="{{ action }}" id="urlsForm" method="POST">
        <label for="id_url">Url:</label></td><td>
        {{ form.url }}
            <input type="submit" value="insert" />
</form>
```

the view:

```
def editSystemSetting(request, id):
    Url = Urls.objects.get(id = id)
    editData = {'url':Url.url}
    URLS = Urls.objects.all()

    form = SaveUrl(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        Url.url=url
        Url.save()
    else:
        form = SaveUrl(editData)


    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
        'urls':URLS,
        'action':'/systemSettings/edit/'+id,
        })
    return render_to_response('systemSettings/urlsSetting.html', variables)
```

Comment: Advices: 1) Use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to make an url and escape of hardcoding it. 2) Use form [as django offers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#using-a-form-in-a-view) 3) For initial data (_edit mode_) use [`initial` kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, just changed the urls.py to:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)$',
    'editSystemSetting',
    name='editSystemSetting'),
```